# Webpack 2: CommonsChunkPlugin issue

Tags: webpack-2

I would like to ask a question about CommonsChunkPlugin

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: ['moment'],
        app: ['./www/build/main.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'chunk'
        })
    ]
}
```

After i run the webpack script, there are 3 files generated (vendor.bundle, app.bundle, chunk.bundle). My questions are:

1. What is the usage chunk.bundle and why it is generated? I set the config in "entry" and output is depends on the [name] of entry
2. How can i run the script to all files under a folder? The current setting needs to input one by one.
3. If my file is too large, how can i split is into some smaller files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) The chunk.bundle.js is being generated by the plugin. It operates a little outside of the usual Webpack flow.

2) Not sure what you're getting at, here. You probably need to look at the `minChunks` setting, or `chunks`.

3) You can use multiple instances of the plugin. I've found that you have to use the `chunks` setting on every instance except for one to avoid getting an error. Basically that specifies on what entry files the plugin will operate. You can specify all your entry files in `chunks`, and then use a function with `minChunks` to filter out what you want to include in that file.